# String replace dash to plus sign htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace

I'm doing a rewrite rewriting my old url structure to my new one, the thing is my old one uses dashes to separate words and my new one uses +'s.

This is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^search/files/(.*)/(.*).html?$ http://www.domain.com/search.html?q=$2 [R=301,L]
```

how could i do a string replace on $2 to replace -'s with +'s?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule **before your existing rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# replace - with + in $2 and $2
RewriteRule ^(search/files/[^/]+)/([^-]*)-+(.+?\.html?)$ /$1/$2+$3 [NC,L,R]

# your present rule
RewriteRule ^search/files/([^/]+)/([^.]+).html?$ http://www.domain.com/search.html?q=$2 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```